# Increase google chart row

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, visualization

How to increase row height in google charts.

[image]

Basically I would like to be able to increase all the row's height.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Google `timeline` chart ?

Comment: yes. I am using the timeline chart.

Comment: no standard options exist for adjusting the row height -- would have to modify svg manually on `'ready'` event

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that?